# Laravel 10 поиск в таблице PostgreSQL без учёта регистра

Tags: laravel, postgresql

У кого то есть элегантный опыт в организации поиска по таблице без учета регистра.

Пример запроса:

```php
$products = Products::query()
    ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function($query, $search) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: можете использовать ilike

Comment: Сейчас стоит Like , но он не ищет без учёта регистра.

Comment: @Igor Вам написали.. ilike используйте вместо like, в postgresql это расширение которое и делает поиск не зависимо от регистра

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою невнимательность, "замылился глаз".

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, проверил, сработал именно **I**LIKE

```html
$products = Products::query()
    ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function($query, $search) {
        $query->where('name', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
    })->get();
```